# How to copy and paste data from one excel workbook to another workbook in filtered column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Not able to copy data from one excel workbook to another excel workbook which has filtered columns.

Tried these methods

1. Paste special->values->skip blanks and
2. ctrl+G->special->visible cells only

Even after trying these methods not able to copy and paste the data. only some of the rows are copied and that too with wrong data.